# Error formato Json datatable "DataTables warning: table id=productos - Invalid JSON response"

Tags: laravel, ajax, json, datatables

Estoy trabajando en laravel 8, intentado mostrar unos productos desde mi bd de forma mas rapida,  que pasar todos los productos y luego hacer paginate con datatable.

Asi que encontré una manera de hacerlo con ajax.

Luego instalé :

> composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle

para poder ejecutar datatable del lado del servidor

pero me sale el error.

```
DataTables warning: table id=productos - Invalid JSON response
```

Esta es mi tabla en la vista, para efectos de prueba solo puse una columna:

```
<table data-page-length='100' id="productos" name="productos" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Imagen</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                </table>
```

Este es mi Ajax:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

  var datatable = $('#productos').DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ajax : "{{ route ('producto.comprar') }}",
    columns : [
      {data: 'id_producto'},
    ],
  });

  });
```

Y este es mi controlador que me regresa los datos, para efectos de prueba solicito un solo producto:

```
public function comprarApi()
    {
        $productos = Producto::where('id_producto', 49359)->get();
        return datatables($productos)->make(true);
        // return Datatables()->collection($productos)->toJson();
    }
```

Este es el modelo de mi tabla Producto:

```
class Producto extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'producto';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_producto';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $guarded = [];

}
```

Por ultimo, cuando hago la prueba con postMan, y veo que me esta devolviendo el controlador.
este me devuelve la siguiente información:

```
{
    "draw": 0,
    "recordsTotal": 1,
    "recordsFiltered": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id_producto": 49359,
            "posi": 38,
            "cod_producto": "18045",
            "descrip_producto": "ABRAZADERA ",
            "referencia_producto": "ABR0",
            "precenta_producto": "PAQ-X1",
            "valor_producto": 200,
            "valor_producto_minorista": 250,
            "iva_producto": 0,
            "fecha_regi": "2021-01-27",
            "Estado_producto": "activo",
            "categoria": 1,
            "descuento": 0
        }
    ],
    "input": []
}
```

No sé que hacer, aparentemente todo esta ok, debe ser algún pequeñez, casi siempre me encuentro que las fallas son chicas, pero no he logrado encontrar cual podría ser la falla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede que se porque la petición te regresa "draw": 0

En el ajax agrega "processing": true,